# WPF Grid detect click outside

Tags: wpf, grid, lostfocus

I want to detect when the user has clicked outside the custom Grid, but when a user clicks on the grid, I allways receive the LostFocus event. Focusable is true, but it seems that the grid never gets focus. Can somebody please help me?

```
public class GridEditor : Grid
{
    public GridEditor()
    {
        Loaded += GridEditor_Loaded;
    }

    private void GridEditor_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Focusable = true;

        this.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(GridEditor_LostFocus);
    }

    void GridEditor_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsKeyboardFocusWithin && !this.IsMouseOver)
        {
            Commands.EditConfirmed.Execute(DataContext, this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am facing the same, i need to do some action when user clicks and edit as he wish but when user click on different element, then i want to sort the entries he has made, lost foucs does the required work but it is also when i click on the grid as well as. do you have solution for this

Answer (score 4):

You may use the `Mouse.Capture(...)` Method to get events of the mouse that are not refering to your grid. This can be pretty helpful if you are drawing lines or anything else. 
Just take a look at this: [Mouse.Capture on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.input.mouse.capture.aspx)